# Window insulator kits performance

Tags: insulation, windows

We live in the snow belt with the temps dropping down to 5-10 for the winter months. The house is 20yo. For the last 2-3 years its windows began to frost overnight, and the heating bill went up.

A few years ago I saw my neighbors install an outdoor window insulator kit. They did it it on a windy day, and I could clearly see that the film that they were working with was thick and somewhat rigid. Since then about 5 years passed, and they've never removed their film, and is still perfectly clear, smooth with no wrinkles, and it held up very well with no cracks or tears.

Now that I shop around for window insulator kits I see the 3 main offerings: 3M, Duck, and Frost King. All of them have reviews that speak of the film being very thin and easy to break. That is not what my neighbor has. Theirs looked more like clear vinyl used in strollers and cloths storage racks than what is found in the above 3 manufacturers' kits.

Since google did not offer any results beyond the 3 above, I am puzzled by the source of my neighbor's kit. Unfortunately I did not see the box that it came in, and I cannot tell what manufacturer it could possibly be. Short of calling HVAC companies, I cannot think of other options to find out where to buy the same kind of product.

Any tips/leads to what that could have been?

Comment: Well, there's always actually asking your neighbors, for one option...

Comment: I've used these film kits over the years.  You can tear the plastic, but without any provocation they will last multiple years.   My typical point of failure is the double sided sticky tape drying out and letting go.  I've built a frames out of 1x2's custom fit to a slider and an alcove window and swap them in every fall.   The plastic will remain clear and smooth after being done over with a hair dryer.

Comment: What I've seen is always on the inside. Outside would have to be thicker to stand up to weather. Keep in mind that (a) if your windows are needed as an emergency exit then you should have nothing or thin/easy-to-break stuff and (b) if you open your windows in nice weather (many people do this a lot, but some "never") then you will need to put the film on fresh each year.

Comment: Was it possible they made their own window insulator kit, maybe out of the plastic used for greenhouses/shelters?

Comment: Most of these window insulator kits are 90% draft stoppers and about 10% insulating.